# Hadoop Distribute File System

Tags: hadoop

I have a doubht in HDFS architecture..

Is there any difference between Name Node and Job tracker? and Data Node and Task tracker?

both are same or each has some specific functionality?

I came to know that Name is considered to the master node . It has  namespace in RAM that has all information about the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference between Name Node and Job tracker?

Two unrelated components. Namenode is part of the HDFS, while Jobtracker is part of mapreduce. Apples and oranges. Ditto for datanode (HDFS) and tasktracker (mapreduce).

Hadoop core consists of two systems: the HDFS filesystem and the mapreduce components. HDFS is file system, it consists at minimum of one namenode (the central catalog) and several datanodes (the actual storage). Mapreduce consists of the job tracker (central 'brain' of mapreduce) and several tasktrackers (executors).

While deployed together, and getting +synergy from how they interact (data locality for compute), they are distinct. There is no point in asking what is common or different between them.